# Should my app target Windows 8.1 before it is widely adopted?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 is the update to Windows 8.0. Right now, using Visual Studio 2012 I can target my Store App to Windows 8.0. But with Visual Studio 2013 I can target Windows 8.1. There are new APIs available, some changes to the framework, and new XAML controls I can use - the date picker control alone will remove third party libraries from my solution.

Knowing the benefits of Windows 8.1's APIs and controls over Windows 8.0, is it worth targeting my app to Windows 8.1 as quickly as it is available (basically, now), or should I wait?

**Please**, this is an honest question that many developers are asking right now. The changes are significant, but the answer to this question is not apparent. Though I can have a Windows 8.0 *and* a Windows 8.1 app in the store, my goal is have a great app with a single code base.

1. Is targeting Windows 8.1 worth it (at all)?
2. Is "early" a valuable-enough quality of an app?
3. Is there some "trigger metric" for adoption?
4. What's the rule of thumb on other platforms?

How should serious developers answer this?

Comment: Yes, it is an honest question.  However, answers will be primarily opinion based therefore making SO an inappropriate forum to ask this question.

Comment: Tell you what, Kevin. I won't disagree with you. But let's just let this question float for a little and see if we can help developers with a common sense discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have "the" answer, but I could share my approach when Windows 8.1 is not a requirement :

- Maintaining two versions of an app (W8 & W8.1) costs. Measure that cost.
- If your application is not already published and is not likely to reach the store before the end of the year go for W8.1.
- If you already have a version of application live on Store, update it as quickly as possible to integrate an analytics solution and gather OSVersion (http://bit.ly/15X2B3K). Decide when you have enough users using W8.1 to justify the migration cost. Plan the drop of W8 support.

Hope this helps